# Why is my question closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

[How can a point-particle have properties?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8179/how-can-a-point-particle-have-properties)

I have edited the parts that were open to criticism. It has 4 upvotes, and people who are trying to answer it in the comments.

Why is it closed?

Should it be closed?

Vote up for open, down for close.

Comment: **High rep users that agree with reopening should not merely upvote this but also vote to reopen the question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was keeping it closed was mostly because of this paragraph:

> Not only that, but it can also detect all fields without having any structure. Maybe it can check curvature of spacetime to account fo gravity, but how does it "sense" what the other fields-vectors are?

Particles are not alive. (I guess we don't know *for certain* but the idea would be exceedingly difficult to support) They don't actively "detect" fields, they don't "check" or "sense" anything and then decide how to react.

Anyway, since nobody else seems to support having the question closed I reopened it.

Comment: Probably a bit late, but I'd  agree that the question was vague and does not really belong to physics Q&A site. I'm probably on the stricter side on this issue - the site is already swamped with low quality questions, in my mind setting some minimum requirement of relevance and quality of questions is not a bad idea. It has been a little while since I've seen a specific and technical question on the level of a graduate student, and if this sort of musings will dominate the front page I don't see that happening very much.